# ifstream not opening .csv file on C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to open this file and parse the data into vectors. However the code does not get past the if statement. I have the .csv in the same folder as the code.

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    
   
    
        string file = "file.csv";
        ifstream open(file);

        if(open.is_open()){
            
          vector<float> rm;
          vector<float> medv;
          
          float _rm;
          float _medv;
          
          char delimiter;
          open.ignore(100,'\n');
            
          while(open >> _rm >> delimiter >> _medv){
            rm.push_back({_rm});
            medv.push_back({_medv});
          }
            Sum(rm);
            Sum(medv);
            Mean(rm);
            Mean(medv);
            
            
            
            
       }
      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `open` is a bad  name choice

Comment: Are you running this from inside an IDE? If so your current working directory might not be the same as your source directory.

Comment: your code should enter the `if` statement, please make the example minimal, and show the compilation line ...

Comment: How are you running the program? What is the working directory? Have you tried using an absolute rather than a relative path for your file?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that the code is not looking for the file in the place you think it should be looking. This is the concept of the *current working directory*. That's where the program will be looking for the file, so in other words the current working directory is not where you think it should be. Since you haven't said anything at all about the environment in which you are running the program its hard to tell you where you should put the file so that your program can find it. I suggest you add some details to the question.

Comment: `I have the .csv in the same folder as the code`. Clearly this is the wrong place. Other places you might try, same folder as the program, same folder as the project, same folder as the console current working directory. Which is these is correct (and it might be that none of them is correct) depends completely on your environment. This issue is nothing to do with C++ which is just following the rules for your particular platform.